# Considering sets as elements and elements as sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, data-analysis

In a data science project, I have $n$ sets, and $k$ elements. Many elements belong to multiple sets. As $k \approx n$, it is convenient to look at these data in both the "straightforward way" (studying all the elements belonging to some set), and what I would call the "dual way": studying all the sets that include some element. In some sense, it amounts to considering sets as elements and elements as sets.
Both approaches are interesting in this project, and I would like to somehow formalize their use in the paper I'm writing.

I am sure this "dual" way to consider elements and sets has been studied somewhere, but I can't find any paper doing this. I guess I do not use the proper search terms. Would you have references?

Comment: You could describe what you’re looking for as a particular subset of the power set.

Comment: Perhaps you could formulate this as a bipartite graph? One group of nodes corresponds to the sets and the other group to the elements, with edges indicating membership. Now, the neighbors of any given node are either (1) the elements of an original set or (2) all the sets containing an element. There might then be some clever graph theory you could use?

Comment: There is a very old subject called entity-relationship modelling that might be relevant. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is fairly open-ended. I'll list a couple of things you can do in no particular order.

Other folks have already mentioned graph theory, especially a bipartite graph, which seems like a very natural choice for representing your relation.

- Matrices and Linear Algebra
- Set theory as a notational tool

---

Since $n$ and $k$ are both finite, one easy thing you can do is organize them into sequences $\vec{d}$ for data and $\vec{s}$ for sets.

After organizing them into sequences, you can represent the elementhood relation as an [incidence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_structure#Incidence_matrix) organized into an [incidence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix).

Let's call the matrix $M$. Every element of $M$ is 0 or 1.

$$ M_{ij} = 1 \;\;\text{if and only if}\;\; \vec{d}_i \; \text{is a member of}\; \vec{s}_j $$

Using the incidence relation $M$, you can construct further matrices that represent distances between elements of $\vec{s}$ or between elements of $\vec{d}$. And you can apply all the familiar tools of linear algebra, matrix multiplication, eigenvalues, characteristic polynomials, rank. The [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) is useful for constructing low-rank approximations to existing matrices, which might also be useful.

---

Set theory gives you some useful notation that might be helpful for defining your own concepts.

I would first define $D$ as your data/elements and $S$ as your sets. $D$ and $S$ are both sets.

You can *choose* to make $S$ a subset of $2^D$, the [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $D$, but you don't have to. You can make both $S$ and $D$ completely abstract. You can define $R(x, y)$ as a relation, using the following definition.

$$ R(x, y) \; \text{if and only if} \; \text{$x$ is in $\vec{d}$ and $y$ is in $\vec{s}$ and $x$ is in the data set $y$} $$

You can also just use $x \in y$ for that purpose if you want the elements of $S$ to be sets of elements of $D$ rather than abstract "arbitrary" entities.

You can now use [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation), which can describe interesting things, especially when combined with the notation $|\cdots|$ which takes the cardinality (size) of a set.

For example, given two elements of $D$ named $x$ and $y$, here is the probability $P(x, y)$ that they will both be inside or both be outside an element of $S$ chosen uniformly at random.

$$ P(x, y) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=\!=} \frac{|\{ R(x, z) \leftrightarrow R(y, z) : z \in S \}| }{|S|} $$

Comment: Thank you very much!