# Is there some dual view of set theory where sets and elements roles are switched?

Tags: set-theory, duality-theorems

In some project, I am comparing some sets on the basis of the elements they contain. My data can be represented as a binary matrix $M$ with sets in rows and elements in colunms. Entry $M_{ij} = 1$ if set $i$ contains elements $j$ and $0$ otherwise.

I am wondering if there exists some theory about switching the roles of sets and elements here, which would correspond to transposing the matrix $M$. This kind of approach would be a "dual view" of the data. Instead of describing sets with the list of elements they contain, we would describe elements with the list of sets they are contained in.

Does that ring a bell to someone?

Comment: In modern set theory, there is no distinction between "elements" and "sets":  everything is a set, and "is  an element of" is a relation between sets. Moreover, even in set theories with "urelements" (elements that are not sets), sets can still be elements of other sets. Finally, while most common set theories are "well founded" (there is a limit to how for "down" you can go: no infinite sequence $x_1,\ldots,x_n,\ldots$ with $x_{i+1}\in x_i$), it is possible to get infinite (transfinite, even) sequences $y_1\in y_2\in\cdots$.

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasonable to describe an element by a  set which contains it. That's what we do when we say n is a natural number, we are describing n by saying it is in the set of all natural numbers. To add to ArturoMagidin's point, sets whose elements are sets, we call hereditary sets. Most set theories only admit hereditary sets.

Comment: Perhaps a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178026/considering-sets-as-elements-and-elements-as-sets

Comment: Thanks, I'ill check that!